# Is there any slang for 絞首刑?

Tags: words, expressions, slang

In English it is quite common to use the expression "to get the chair" to refer to the death penalty. For example:

> He committed such a terrible crime, I hope **he gets the chair**. *

The word 絞首刑, "death by hanging", is the only Japanese word I know in this regard. Is there any slang (such as "to get the rope") that can be used to indicate someone who was/will be sentenced to death?

* *This example is **by no means** related to me being in favor or against the death penalty.*

Comment: Not slang, but there's 死刑, which is at at least more common/colloquial than 絞首刑.
https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E6%AD%BB%E5%88%91

Comment: @Mindful yes I know  死刑. I'm asking if there is some slang or "colorful expression" to refer to it.

Comment: 縛り首？ But it's too anachronistic to be used in the 21st century IMO...

Comment: @broccoliforest thanks, but in what sense you say it's anachronistic?

Comment: @Tommy that you'd sound as if in a period drama.

Comment: Japan has the death penalty but it’s not as controversial as in western countries. When those responsible for the 1995 Sarin gas attacks were executed, it barely made the news. I’m not aware of any euphemisms for it. I suspect because Japanese people would unashamedly state what happened. It’s not in their culture to question the what has been decided in court.

Answer (score 1):

There might be yakuza slang for it, but there isn’t a common phrase for it. My gut feeling is that death just isn’t something Japanese joke about as much as eg Americans do.

Comment: 死ね is used commonly by many people who chat.